# [iPhone]how to catch signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"?

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, signals, try-catch

i would like to log every crash of my application...

so i've tried to catch all signals. But it seems not working for "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Someone know... If is it possible to catch it ? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this automatically with [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com).

Answer (score 1):

[The zombies will save you.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is probably SIGBUS or SIGKILL. See PLCrashReporter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an argument on your executable called `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`.

Comment: Is this recommended for distribution if I want to catch EXEC_BAD_ACCESS? For a specific case, I want nothing to happen (like sending a message to `nil`), where there's a chance that a message will be sent to an object after its been deallocated. Basically, I want ARC's weak pointers.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out how to do this a better way by [retaining the request delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528866/ok-to-retain-asihttprequest-delegate/6529193#comment-7688197).